# javax.script on Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to port my Java project to Android devices, the problem I am facing is, that I need javax.script library. So the question is:
Is it possible to import *javax.script* to an Android project? And if so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to port the entire javax.script package, and any other packages it depends on to Android and compile them as a library, then yes. Otherwise, no.